# JSON Path Selector

Tags: json

I have the following record:

```
{
"reply_time" :   {"calendar":60,"business":60}
}
```

If want to have only 60 selected from the above. how can I achieve that. I am not that familiar with JSON path expression.

I want the final output as:

```
{
"reply_time" : 60
}
```

I tried something like the below.

reply_time = [*].

Comment: What to select in case {calendar":60,"business":30}?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var item = {
  reply_time: { calendar: 60, business: 60 },
};

item.reply_time = item.reply_time.calendar;

console.log(JSON.stringify(item));
```

result

```
{
"reply_time" : 60
}
```